# Linking an annotation to an identifier - Swift, MapKit

Tags: swift, mapkit

So, I've created an annotation. The annotation appears on my map but I want to change it's view. I'm not sure how to set it's identifier though.

If you are answering this question, please use my code within it, not an example because I get really confused.

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
    let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.809335, 151.258695)
    let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Bus Stop"
    annotation.subtitle = "Street Name at Street Name"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)
    -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView

        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(
            withIdentifier: identifier)
            as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,
                                          reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.markerTintColor = UIColor.blue
            view.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "small-business-20")
            view.selectedGlyphImage = UIImage(named: "small-business-40")
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }
        return view
}

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapView.view(for:)` method to get the MKMarkerAnnotationView.

```
@IBAction func hoge(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let ann = self.mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        ann.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "Laugh")
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, you can use that as `IBAction`. I edited my answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question though